# How to paste JSON as PHP array in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am calling a third-party API, the parameter is in `json` format. Is it possible to copy the JSON and paste into PhpStorm as PHP array? That is, automatically convert JSON to PHP array.

Comment: There are plugins for such conversion .. but they are for TypeScript, Java, Kotlin, XML. Even for other way around (even more formats) -- e.g. JsonToTS, JsonMaster etc. But I see **nothing** for PHP arrays there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a phpstorm plugin

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17626-php-array-converter

Even though the question is over a year old,
I hope it will serve other users